# install vitualenv has error could not find that satisfies the requirement vitual env

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-venv

[image]

When I try to install vitualenv it says :

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement vitualenv(from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for vitualenv

What should I do??

Comment: Check the spelling it should be `pip install virtualenv` not vitualenv